# Having problems understanding this algebraic expression

Tags: decimal-expansion

So I have a solution where $B = 0.1959552$ and $A = 0.00048515$.

The problem asks, $A$ is $10$ times more likely than $B$. The teacher wrote (i.e. $A = 10 \cdot B$). Is this the right notation or shouldn't it be that you multiply $A$ by $10$?

Comment: Do you mean $P(A) = 10\cdot P(B)$?  What do your numbers in the first paragraph have to do with the probabilities of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I just want to know how should I calculate this problem. Because I'm kind of confused. Do I multiply A by 10 or B by 10?

Comment: If $A$ is $10$ times $B$, then $A=10\cdot B$.